# Getting user checkins via facebook graph api (in version >= 2.0)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to ask following question

Does anyone know how to receive the user's checkins in the facebook via Facebook Graph API 2.0 and up? As far as I got /me/checkins is deprecated.

Thx in advance

Best regards

Answer (score 8):

There is no such thing like checkins anymore as far as I know. You can query either for

- Place Tags
- Posts with an included location

like the follwoing

- `/me/tagged_places`
- `/me/posts?with=location`

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed/#read
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/tagged_places/

Comment: That´s just what I needed. But instead post?whith=location I used me/feed?fields=from,full_picture,id,type,link,place&limit=50&with=location